# Not showing Space (either it is Allocated or Free) as well as the Partition created for it, while installing Ubuntu 16.04 or 17.10 on my Asus Laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, partitioning, boot-partition

I want my system to have Windows 10 and Ubuntu both. Right now, I have Windows 10 only & I want to install Ubuntu 17.10 along with Windows 10. Following online tutorials, I performed the USB flash drive booting using Rufus and then made an unallocated partition about 100 GB for installing Ubuntu. Using flash drive of 8 GB, I was installing the Ubuntu but I got stuck at the step installing Ubuntu on the given partition. **The Problem was that the partition which I made was not showing (in windows-I had 4 partitions and an unallocated space but it was only showing 2 partitions excluding the system reserved partition)**. So, I thought this may be solved if make my unallocated partition to allocated. But still, the problem persists. At last, I thought that this might not happen with Ubuntu 16.04, so I tried out the same step with 16.04 version. But again, I got stuck with the same problem.

This is the image taken while installing Ubuntu 17.10 (the same scenario was in Ubuntu 16.04) at the Disk partition step. Here, you can see that Partition which I allocated is not showing. A 100 GB space was allocated for it (see in the following images). Once tried with Allocated Space and once, with unallocated.

[image]

I have a partition with 100 GB of Unallocated Space:

[image: Image- Unallocated space]

I have a partition with 100 GB of Allocated Space:

[image: Image- Allocated space]

Comment: What's your actual question here?  Note that Windows can't read Linux partitions, so you might not see it as 'allocated space' in Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a Windows Dynamic Disk?](/q/179215/175814)

Comment: Its really a Windows issue. You have to undo the proprietary dynamic partitions. See also. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758